# Finding user's app version with firebase function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am writing a function with firebase cloud function. Is there a way to find out which version of the application the mobile user is using?
what i want to do is this: function will work differently if the user is using version 1.2.4 and earlier of my app. It will work differently if using version 1.2.5 and above.

Answer (score 2):

I'm currently unaware of any version information that is exposed in the authentication tokens or the API calls themselves out of the box. Implementing such detections is a responsibility of the author and in certain regions, collecting such data must be communicated to the end user.

Going forward, each time you make a function call, either:

- include an ordinal version whenever your API changes (e.g. `{ v: 1 }` in the request body, or `?v=1` or `/v1/endpoint` in the URL), or
- include the true app version after seeking the appropriate permissions (e.g. `{ app: 'and.1.2.6' }` in the request body, or `?app=and.1.2.6` or `/and-1.2.6/endpoint` in the URL).